# If it is possible to add custom menu item on wp_nav_menu with reverse order

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

I'm trying to add a custom menu item on my website. its showing perfectly but i need to show reverse order format.

It is like this screenshot:

[image]

**Function Code is:**

```
  add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_custom_in_menu', 10, 2);
function add_custom_in_menu( $items, $args ) {

    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= "<li>
        <div class='userView'> <img class='background' src='".get_bloginfo('template_url')."/assets/images/sidenav-logo-bg.png'> <a href='.'><img src='".get_bloginfo('template_url')."/assets/images/logo-mdm.png' class='responsive-img'></a> </div>
        <div class='show-on-med-and-down nav-social'>
        <a href='#' target='_blank' class='facebook'><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i></a>
              <a href='#' target='_blank' class='twitter'><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i></a>
              <a href='#' target='_blank' class='google'><i class='fa fa-google-plus'></i></a>
              <a href='#' target='_blank' class='linkdin'><i class='fa fa-linkedin'></i></a>
              <a href='#' class='email'><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i></a>
         </div>
      </li>";
    }

    return $items;
}
```

**Menu linking code on header**

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
            <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
                <?php
                    //  navigation menu.
                    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'orderby' => 'menu_order') );
                ?>

            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

I need reverse order like logo should be on top and others are looping below logo. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you *append* logo (all the stuff inside `<li>`) to `$items` string. What you should instead is *prepend* it, like this:

```
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
  $items = "<li>\\ template is skipped for readability \\</li>" . $items;
}
return $items;
```

You might consider extracting logo template generation into a separate function.